# How to tell for which executable the firefox driver running in task manager (firefox.exe) is connected?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

We are running in a server here some robots that are using Selenium Firefox.exe, but sometimes, a lot of instances of firefox.exe are getting stuck on task manager even if the executable has already finished. There is a way that I can check for which robot this firefox.exe is related to know which programs are having problems and are not closing those instances?

Comment: When your program lunch the selenium driver, store the PID of executed Firefox in dictionary of Robot-PID and later you can find the matching robot which lunch specific Firefox instance.

Comment: I found a solution where before instantiating the firefox driver, I get the list of firefox processes that are running and then after instantiating I do it again but using Except method to get just the difference, so the list that I will get are the processes that start running after Firefox Driver instantiation.